# In Answer Set Programming, what is the difference between a model and a least model?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I'm taking an artificial intelligence class and we are working with Answer Set Programming (Clingo specifically). We're talking mostly theory at the moment and I am having some trouble differentiating between models and least models. I have the following definitions:

> Satisfying rules, models, least models and answer sets of definite
>   program
>
> 1. A program is called definite if it does not have “not” in the body of its rules.
> 2. A set S is said to satisfy a rule of the form  a :- b1, …, bm, not c1, …, not cn. if  its body is satisfied by S (I.e., b1 … bm are in S
>      and none of c1 ... cn are in S) implies that its head must be
>      satisfied by S (i..e, a is in S).
> 3. A set S is said to satisfy a program if it satisfies all rules of that program.
> 4. A set S is said to be an answer set of a definite program P if  (a) S satisfies P (also referred to as S is a model of P)  and (b)  No
>      strict subset of S satisfies P (i.e., S is the least model of P).

With the question (pulled from the lecture slides, not homework):

```
P is defined as:
a :- b,e.
b. 
c :- d,b.
d.

Which of the following are models and least models?
{}, {b}, {b,d}, {b,d,c}, {b,d,c,e}, {b,d,c,e,a}
```

Can anyone let me know what the answer to the above question is? I can probably figure out the difference from there, although if someone could explain the difference in common speak (rather than text-book definition), that would be wonderful. I'm not sure which forum to post this question under - please let me know if it should be posted somewhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that this section of your slides is talking about the answer sets of a *positive program* **P** (also called a *definite program*), even though it mentions also *not*. The positive program is the simple case, as for a positive program **P** there always exists a unique least model **LM**(**P**), which is the intersection of all it's models.

Allowing *not* rules in the rule *bodies* makes things more complex. The *body* of a rule is the right side of `:-`.

The answer to the question would be, set by set:

- S={} is **not a model**, since b and d are facts `b. d.`
- S={b} is **not a model**, since d is a fact `d.`
- S={b,d} is **not a model**, since c is implied by `c :- d,b.` and c is not in S
- S={b,d,c} is a **model**
- S={b,d,c,e} is **not a model**, since a is implied by `a :- b,e.` and a is not in S
- S={b,d,c,e,a} is a **model**

So what is the least model? It's S={b,c,d} since no strict subset of S satisfies **P**.

We can arrive to the least model of a positive program **P** in two ways:

- Enumerate all models and take their intersection (here {b,c,d}∩{a,b,c,d,e}={b,c,d}).
- Starting with the facts (here `b. d.`) and iteratively adding implied atoms (here `c :- b,d.`) to S, repeating until S is a model and stopping at that point.

Like your slides say, the definition of an *answer set* for a *positive program* **P** is: S is an answer set of **P** if S is the least model of *P*. To be stricter, this is actually *if and only if*, since the least model **LM**(**P**) is unique.

As a last note, so you are not later confused by them, a *constraint* `:- a, b` is actually just shorthand for `x :- not x, a, b`. Thus programs containing constraints are not positive programs; though they might look like they are at first, since the body of a constraint seemingly doesn't contain a *not*.